# Handling data logic on libgdx ai state machine or in ashley system?

Tags: libgdx, entity-system, fsm, entity

In this below example, I've combined libgdx ashley and AI state machine. Do you think it's a good idea to handle the logic in state machine or stick on handling the data logic on System?

```
public enum TrollState implements State<Entity> {
     MOVE_AWAY() {
         @Override
         public void enter(Entity entity) {

         }

         @Override
         public void update(Entity entity) {
              PositionComponent position = Mappers.position.get(entity);
              ...
         }

         @Override
         public void exit(Entity entity) {

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMessage(Entity entity, Telegram telegram) {
             if (telegram.message == 0) {
                 Gdx.app.log("Slime", "Waaaah, goo away, big daddy! yummmmmmy");
                 return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless there's a specific reason you'd need (want) to process the data in a `State` you should probably stick to Ashley's own `EntitySystem`. Without you yourself expanding the functionality of `State`, `EntitySystem`s are for sure more flexible, as in you can tell it to not process the system, you can do something when it's added / removed etc.

Also the development team for Ashley probably optimized their framework as much as possible, meaning that even though it might be a small increase the `EntitySystem`s are probably faster.

If you wish to use Ashley together with GdxAI's States perhaps you could implement it by creating a `Component` and `EntitySystem` that handles the states for you:

```
// Component example
public class StateComponent<T> implements Component {
    private State<T> state;

    public StateComponent(State<T> state) {
        this.state = state;
    }
    //  Other methods omitted for clarity.
}
```

```
// System example
public class StateSystem<T> extends IteratingSystem {

    private YourCustomStateMachine machine = new YourCustomStateMachine();

    public StateSystem() {
        super(Family.all(StateComponent<T>).getFamily());
    }

    @Override
    public void update(float deltaTime) {
        super.update(deltaTime);
        // Make sure to update machine in the update() method so it only 
        // runs once per frame and not once per entity.
        machine.update();
    }

    @Override
    protected void processEntity(Entity entity, float deltaTime) {
        //Process the entity and update states as usual.
    }
}
```

For a more generalized question on `Finite State Machines` and `Component Based Programming` see [this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/24603/how-to-wire-finite-state-machine-into-component-based-architecture?rq=1).

Comment: So are you saying that, you recommend useing FSM states as state only and handle the data logic purely to the ECS system.

Comment: Exactly. In fact, you should maybe even have a `StateComponent` and `StateSystem` have those store your entities state as well (if you don't already have it set up like this).

Comment: That's the word I want others to metion, That using StateComponent and StateSystem is better. I have these in my mind, but still having doubts because FSM states and states could make a redundant data.

Comment: You could edit and make a brief explanation about StateComponent  and StateSystem, so I could mark this as an answer.

Comment: what do you recommend to use in `StateComponent`, integer of state/states or an enum of state/states?

Comment: If you wish to not use GdxAi's states I would recommend using Enums. (GdxAi recommend this themselves! Take a look at the first bullet point under **"IMPORTANT NOTES"** on their [official wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/gdx-ai/wiki/State-Machine#the-state-interface).)